# Django admin css not loading

Tags: django, django-admin

It's strange because I look in my public folder and see that the file admin has the contents

```
link /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin
```

And when I go to that location on my server the files are all there but it doesn't seem to actually link there. It's the same for the auth file. I could copy the files over but I don't think that's the correct way. What's strange is that this worked before

My **url.py (the relevant lines)**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url 
from views import *

from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout


# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:

from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',

(r'^admin/',include(admin.site.urls)),

)


urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
# url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Comment: Did you upgrade Django? Can you post your settings.py? Also urls.py.

Answer (score 1):

Might be that you are using `python manage.py runserver`, and having DEBUG=False? If so you must add `--insecure` option:

```
python manage.py runserver --insecure
```